# check if update was successful

Tags: php, mysql

I was have the following code that updates a table. I want it to proceed with the update only if all the fields of the update form are filled with values and not empty.

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$newphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['newphone']);
$newemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['newemail']);

$sql="UPDATE users SET PhoneNumber='$newphone', email='$newemail'  WHERE name='$_SESSION[user]'";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Status info have been updated";
print "</h2><br><a href='index.php'>Return to Main Menu</a><br>";



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Never mind the mysql code.I will change it into mysqli afterwards.

Comment: Look into the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

Comment: use if(!empty($sql) { ur condition } ??

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you saying you need to issue an error message to the user if either the `newphone` or `newemail` field is not filled in, and refrain from doing the `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Exactly!If there is an empty field, the update query should not proceed with updating the table with empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if they exist. You need to check this on the back-end and front-end
Here's on back-end:

```
if($_POST['newemail'] && $_POST['newphone'] && $_SESSION['user']) {
    //run sql update
}
```

Front-end:

```
var email = document.getElementById("newemail");
var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
if(phone.value && email.value) {
    //run submission
}
```

Comment: thanks.That's the answer i was looking for.It totally worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

your query will not update anything
Try following code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$sql="UPDATE users SET PhoneNumber='$newphone', email='$newemail'  WHERE name='$user'";
```

in order to check number of updated record

```
mysqli_affected_rows($con);
```